# How to compare Two Resultset Columns values in Java?

Tags: java, jdbc

Can anyone tell me how I can compare two `resultset` values? Only getting error in if statement, but the rest is working.

```
Statement s = con.createStatement();
Statement stmnt = con.createStatement();
String query = "select * from tbl_product";
s.execute(query);
ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet();
while(rs.next())
{
    String strOuter=rs.getString(2);
    System.out.println(strOuter);
    String query1 = "select * from PRODUCTS_AJ";
    stmnt.execute(query1);
    ResultSet rs1 = stmnt.getResultSet();
    while(rs1.next())
    {                   
        System.out.println("-------"+rs1.getString(2));
        if(rs.getString(2).equals(rs1.getString(2)))// Getting Error here for this line
        {
            System.out.println("Found");
        }
    }              
}
```

`java.sql.Exception` data not found

Comment: And the full stack trace of the exception is?

Comment: As an aside, why don't you use 1 query that does the comparing for you?

Comment: @SazzadurRahaman "different connections/statements" : this will increase the overhead a lot !

Answer (score 1):

This types of error occurs when you try to read same column of the same cursor multiple times. And what you encountered is a typical scenario. Just store the string temporarily like bellow:

```
String col3 = rs1.getString(2);
```

and use `col3` instead of `rs1.getString(2)`, whenever needed.

```
    System.out.println("-------"+ col3);
    if(col3.equals(rs1.getString(2)))
    {
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot re-read a column value again. So, copy it in a local variable for logging.

```
String val = rs1.getString(2);
System.out.println("-------" + val);

if (rs.getString(2).equals(val)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could possibly do is

use SQL where clause

```
String query1 = "select * from PRODUCTS_AJ where fieldNmae = 'something'";

    ResultSetMetaData rsm = rs.getMetaData();
    int colCount = rsm.getColumnCount();

if (colCount > 1)
{
// found
}
```

For [ResultSetMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnCount%28%29)

or possibly do

```
ResultSet rsOLD = null;
ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet(); 
// rs will be new ResultSet 

while(condition)
{

// check from second row (maintain if case)
.
.
.

// end of loop

      rsOLD = rs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok ! This is a typical error while using JDBC-ODBC bridge driver with MS Access. I have experienced.I solved it in following way. Retrieving the same data more than once from the result set.
Please try like this

```
ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet();
String str=rs.getString(2);
```

Use this string to compare

```
str.equals(rs2.getString(2)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`rs.getSting(2)` is executed the number of row times of rs1 in the while loop of rs1. You may not have the that many number of rows in rs as rs1.